# How can multiple text-boxes in ProPresenter slides be edited by a third party program?

Tags: presentations

## Question

How can multiple text-boxes in ProPresenter slides be edited by a third party program?

### Background

I want to edit the text-boxes in ProPresenter slides without editing them individually, so the main text and the translation are in seperate text-boxes. Ideally, I would prefer a function in ProPresenter to import a text file with segmented source and target translation text, but this functionality does not exist.

### Details on what we want to do

Modify .prox files, and edit multiple slides, each with two text boxes, inserting a text in one, and its translation in the other. The texts come from SDL Trados, which can export translation projects as a segmented text file with source and target translation. We would like to do this by writing our own program, but there is too little documentation about .prox files.

## Research done so far

I have looked for documentation for .prox files, and if there is a ProPresenter API. There is an API, but nothing about editing text boxes or slides is mentioned. I have looked through StackExchange, and found answers for PowerPoint files.

### Why past questions aren't relevant

PowerPoint isn't part of the production cycle, and the answers given are specific to that program.

## Relevant information

Of a few people working with ProPresenter, together we can program a bit of C++, Python, and write programs in Mathematica. Regular use of ProPresenter. Regular use of SDL Trados.